# Drag and drop selected code in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I'm trying to do this in a plain VS 2015 it starts another selection instead of moving the selected part. Is there any setting for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-enable it by going to the "Tools Menu -> Options" then in treeview select Text Editor -> General (or any specific language) then check the "Drag and Drop Text Editing":

[image]